# makefile for creating new python

Tags: makefile, automation

I am trying to make a makefile that will ask the user for the name of the input and append this to create a $$(file).py but when I try and run this with "make do"

I get this error [image]

```
do :
    @echo "What is the name of the file?: "; \
    read file; \
    touch $$(file).py
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there perchance a file named `do` in your working directory?

Comment: there is none sorry!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots to SO when asking for coding help.  Please cut and paste text into your question, properly formatted.  Screenshots can't be searched and the text in them can't be copied.

Comment: Are you sure that the first character on the second line (the one containing the `@echo ...`) is a real TAB character, not just spaces?  If you remove the `:` from the echo'd text `name of the file?:` so it says just `name of the file?` with no colon, then run `make do`, do you get an error?  If so, the first character on that line is NOT a TAB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
.PHONY: do

do:
    @echo "What is the name of the file?: "; \
    read file && touch "$${file}.py"
```

`.PHONY` is to identify that "do" is not a file that make should look for, this will solve your error. [[more info]](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_node/make_34.html)

I made some changes too, by putting together the read and touch I removed weird outputs in between the 2 commands.

Comment: it did not work unfortunately,
here is my code:


All: do
.PHONY: do
do:
    @echo "What is the name of the file?: "; \
    read file && touch "$${file}.py"

Comment: make sure you have tabs instead of spaces, and that there is no extra spaces or tabs where there is no need for them.